# Correct tense of "rise" in the given context

Tags: tense

Here is the sentence:

> "You rise so early this morning!"

The context is that a wife is surprised to see her husband awake in the early morning. In my view, the correct verb should be "have risen". Am I correct?

Comment: Regardless of tense, native speakers would be *extremely* unlikely to use the verb ***to rise*** in your context. We'd usually say ***You're up** [so / very / really] early this morning!* Or perhaps *You **got up** very early!* if we wanted to focus more on the past activity rather than (more naturally, imho) focusing on the speaker's *current* surprise.

Comment: Also note that there's often quite a lot of difference between ***to wake up, to be awake*** and ***to rise, to be/get up***.

Comment: The wife would only say this if she was a non-native speaker or a robot pretending to be human (which happens from time to time, especially in television fiction).  Most would say "You woke up so early this morning."

Comment: You're getting up so early this morning.

Comment: When Moby Dick surfaces, Ahab exclaims, "He rises!"  That's a really good use of "to rise".

Comment: **this morning** can mean different things.  If it is still morning as the words are spoken, we can be speaking about the *present* but not necessarily so. The speaker could mean "earlier" this morning, in which case the reference is to the past.. But if it is now afternoon  or evening when the words are spoken, we are talking about the *past*.  So that present,  present perfect, and simple past could all be valid there.

Answer (score 2):

> You have risen so early this morning.

is correct but probably not the most usual way to express this.

If the wife mentioned this some time after the husband woke up, for example, while they're eating breakfast, she'd more likely use the past tense:

> You rose so early this morning.

Or if she said it while he is still in bed, she would use the present continuous tense:

> You are rising so early this morning.

It's also much more common to use a more colloquial term than "rise". For example,

> You *got up* so early this morning.
>
> You *were up* really early this morning.
>
> You *woke up* pretty early this morning.

Comment: Honestly, I can't think of any context where someone would use "rise", "rose", or "are rising" in this way.  The only place I've ever heard it is in the idiomatic phrase "to rise up early (in the morning)", spoken as a kind of *general truth*, but it would sound very odd in conversation.  "Wake up", "get up", "get out of bed", etc. are much more natural.

Comment: I agree with Andrew. No one uses rise, except in limited literary contexts.

Answer (score 0):

While the verb "to rise" can mean "to wake up", it's a little too formal for casual conversation.  Here are some idiomatic expressions where it is used:

> to **rise** up early (in the morning)
>
> to **rise** with the dawn.
>
> an early-**riser**.
>
> **rise and shine**.
>
> Early to bed and early to **rise**, makes a man healthy, wealthy and wise.
>
> (to be) the first/last to **rise**.

and a few others.  Aside from these it would be unusual to use "rise" as you describe in your example.  Most people would use a different idiomatic expression, like those outlined in The Photon's answer ("got up", "woke up", etc.)

As a side note, "rise" is also common when talking about *rising* from the dead, as when Christians talk about Jesus' resurrection:

> He **is risen**.

This can give "rise" a nuanced meaning:

> You certainly *slept like the dead* last night, but I see you've **risen** in time for breakfast.